# Bootstrap-vue - Display array data as dropdown in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I have an array of JSON data like :

```
 loggers = [{
        "allAvailableLevel": ['WARN', 'DEBUG', 'INFO'],
        "level": "WARN",
        "logger": "com.test1",
        "status": "success"
    },
{
        "allAvailableLevel": ['WARN', 'DEBUG', 'INFO'],
        "level": "WARN",
        "logger": "com.test2",
        "status": "success"
    }
    ]
```

I am using dropdown inside a table column and for that using below code, and basically traversing Loggers array but not able to extract allAvailableLevel data.

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>Current Level</th>
            <th>All Available Levels</th>
            <!-- Only display "Action" header if level is changed-->
            <th>
              Action
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="(logger, index) in loggers" :key="logger">
            <td>{{ index + 1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ logger.logger }}</td>
            <td>{{ logger.level }}</td>
            <td>
              <b-dropdown
                boundary="viewport"
                id="dropdown-dropup"
                size="sm"
                :text="selectedLevelText"
                split
                class="m-2"
              >
                <b-dropdown-item-button
                  v-for="logger in loggers[0].allLevel"
                  :key="logger"
                  @click.prevent="changeLevel(level)"
                  >{{ logger }}</b-dropdown-item-button
                >
              </b-dropdown>
            </td>
            <td v-if="levelChanged">
              <b-button
                size="sm"
                variant="secondary "
                @click.prevent="updateLevel(selectedLevelText)"
                >Update</b-button
              >
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

with above code my dropdown looks like :

[image]

I want to display it like this :

[image]

How do I traverse my data inside the vue template to get only the data of "allAvailableLevel"?

[image]

Comment: What is `loggers` inside `v-for="logger in loggers"`?

Comment: @palaѕн loggers is an array of json data which I have mentioned above.

Comment: Then try `v-for="logger in loggers[0].allAvailableLevel"` and update text like `{{ logger }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should iterate over that nested array as follows :

```
 <b-dropdown-item-button
                      v-for="level in logger.allAvailableLevel"
                      :key="level"
                      @click.prevent="changeLevel(level)"
                      >{{ level }}</b-dropdown-item-button
                    >
```

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question, now I have more than one element , so hardcoding with Loggers[0] would not solve the problem.

Comment: it seems that you're looping over that array in order to generate a table with a column containing a dropdown, please share that table code

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
<tr v-for="(logger, index) in loggers" :key="logger">
  <td>{{ index + 1 }}</td>
  ...
  <td>
    <b-dropdown
      boundary="viewport"
      id="dropdown-dropup"
      size="sm"
      :text="selectedLevelText"
      split
      class="m-2"
    >
      <b-dropdown-item-button
        v-for="level in logger.allAvailableLevel"
        :key="level"
        @click.stop="changeLevel(level)"
        >{{ logger }}</b-dropdown-item-button
      >
    </b-dropdown>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: But how can we do it without hardcoding loggers[0]?